# Does a woman have to be covered when saying dua, dhikr, and repentence?

Tags: women

Does a woman have to be covered (like when shes praying) to say dua, dhikr, and repentance(tawba)? If the answer is yes then what if a woman is on her period? She still has to cover?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dua and Dhikr *can* be done in any state: menses or no menses, covered or not covered.

> #### الذين يذكرون الله قياما وقعودا وعلى جنوبهم
>
> Who remember Allah while standing or sitting or [lying] on their sides
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:191](http://quran.com/3/191)</sup>

> #### كان النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم يذكر الله على كل أحيانه
>
> The Prophet ﷺ used to remember Allah in all situations.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/147)</sup>